# Ng Image Slider require Click to show the images otherwise It keep loading

Tags: slider, carousel, slideshow, angular-carousel

I am opeing the slider using

this.slider?.showLightbox(); method

The problem is that it keep laoding untill I click somewhere. On click it show the images which are already laoded.
I have applied all techniques like this.cdr.detectchanges, applies maunual click to the image in slider or element in our html but it still require my click on any part of the slider to show the images.

[image: The is the loader appear unless i click somewhere then the images are shown]

Here is the npm package link

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-image-slider